# Defeat these dashed dashes in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, unicode, non-ascii-characters

I have a table that contains the names of various recording artists. One of them has a dash in their name. If I run the following:

```
Select artist
, substring(artist,8,1) as substring_artist
, ascii(substring(artist,8,1)) as ascii_table
, ascii('-') as ascii_dash_key /*The dash key next to zero */
, len(artist) as len_artist 
From [dbo].[mytable] where artist like 'Sleater%'
```

Then the following is returned. This seems to indicate that a dash (ascii 45) is being stored in the artist column

[image]

However, if I change the where clause to:

```
From [dbo].[mytable] where artist like 'Sleater' + char(45) + '%'
```

I get no results returned. If I copy and paste the output from the artist column into a hex editor, I can see that the dash is actually stored as E2 80 90, the Unicode byte sequence for the multi-byte hyphen character.

[image]

So, I'd like to find and replace such occurrences with a standard ascii hyphen, but I'm am at a loss as to what criteria to use to find these E2 80 90 hyphens?

Comment: Don't forget that there is the `hyphen-minus` character (unicode 0x002D), and there is the `en-dash` character (unicode 0x2013) which look very similar. See [Unicode® character table](https://unicode-table.com/en/) for reference.

Comment: Replacing your uses of `ASCII` with [`UNICODE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/functions/unicode-transact-sql) should shed more light on things.

Comment: The character that is actually stored in the DB is `U+2010 HYPHEN`, not `U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS`. Your use of `ASCII()` is transliterating `U+2010` into `U+002D` per the Unicode standard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your char is the hyphen, information on it here :

https://www.charbase.com/2010-unicode-hyphen

You can see that the UTF16 code is 2010 so in T-SQL you can build it with

```
SELECT NCHAR(2010)
```

From there you can use any SQL command with that car, for example in a select like :

```
Select artist
From [dbo].[mytable] where artist like N'Sleater' + NCHAR(2010) + '%'
```

or as you want in a

```
REPLACE( artist, NCHAR(2010), '-' )
```

with a "real" dash

**EDIT:**

If the collation of your DB give you some trouble with the NCHAR(2010) you can also try to use the car N'‐' that you'll copy/paste from the charbase link I gave you so :

```
REPLACE( artist , N'‐' , '-'  )
```

that you can even take from the string here (made with the special car) so all made for you :

```
update mytable set artist=REPLACE( artist, N'‐' , '-' )
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know your table definition and COLLATION but I'm almost sure that you are mixing NCHAR and CHAR types and convert unicode, multibyte characters to sinle byte representations. Take a look at this demo:

```
WITH Demo AS
(
  SELECT N'ABC'+NCHAR(0x2010)+N'DEF' T
)
SELECT
  T,
  CASE WHEN T LIKE 'ABC'+CHAR(45)+'%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END [Char],
  CASE WHEN T LIKE 'ABC-%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END [Hyphen],
  CASE WHEN T LIKE N'ABC‐%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END [Unicode-Hyphen],--unicode hyphen us used here
  CASE WHEN T LIKE N'ABC'+NCHAR(45)+N'%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END [NChar],
  CASE WHEN CAST(T AS varchar(MAX)) LIKE 'ABC-%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END [ConvertedToAscii],
  ASCII(NCHAR(0x2010)) ConvertedToAscii,
  CAST(SUBSTRING(T, 4, 1) AS varbinary) VarbinaryRepresentation
FROM Demo
```

My results:

```
T       Char        Hyphen      Unicode-Hyphen NChar       ConvertedToAscii ConvertedToAscii VarbinaryRepresentation
------- ----------- ----------- -------------- ----------- ---------------- ---------------- --------------------------------------------------------------
ABC‐DEF 0           0           1              0           1                45               0x1020
```

UTF-8 (3 bytes) representation is the same as 2010 in unicode.

Comment: Had the same results when I ran it against my data - thanks!